# SQL figuring out unduplicated clients

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I'm trying to figure out.

> Number of unduplicated clients seen with a BMI at or above the 85th percentile, within the time frame of 1/1/15-9/30/15.

Clients can come in multiply times during the time frame, and right now I'm pulling up unduplicated clients, but when their BMI changes, if they come in a 2nd/3rd/4th/etc time they are counted as a new unduplicated client.

When I only want to count when they first came in with their BMI score.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         COUNT(PATIENT.PATIENT_NO) Custom,
         PATIENT.PATIENT_NO Patient_no,
         Vsfile.BMI_SCORE Bmi_score
    FROM VSFILE Vsfile
         INNER JOIN PATIENT PATIENT
                 ON Vsfile.PATIENT_NO = PATIENT.PATIENT_NO
   WHERE (((Vsfile.BMI_SCORE > 1)
     AND (PATIENT.ENCOUNTER_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '09/30/2015')))
GROUP BY PATIENT.PATIENT_NO,
         Vsfile.BMI_SCORE
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to return their BMI as well?

If not, just stop grouping on it, e.g.:

```
Select count(distinct patient_no)
From my tables
Where BMIPercentile > .85 
  and encounter_date BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '09/30/2015'
```

If you do, then you'll either want some additional criteria - e.g. take the `max` of each patient's BMI values - or a `windowed` function.

As a side note, my answer here assumes you are using SQL server, but in general you'll have more luck if you tag your question with the type of SQL you are using (SQL server, MySQL, Oracle...).